# Как сделать bakground активной ссылкой?

Tags: css, битрикс

Есть сайт с фоном в виде картинки (прописан в css).

Как сделать так, чтобы при клике на этот фон (картинку) автоматически происходил переход на заданную страницу? Сайт на битриксе.

Понятно, что в css ссылку прописать нельзя. Вопрос, куда тогда код влепить, и какой именно?

Сейчас, в сss прописан такой:

```
background: #fff url(images/background.jpg) fixed center center no-repeat;
```

Comment: Вам нужно по клику на body элемент переходить на какой-то сайт?  
Я правильно вас понял?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

внутри `div` c  этим фоном сделать вашу ссылку `<a href="your_link" class="test_class"></a>`

саму ссылку сделать блочной, пропишите стили

```
.test_class {  
    position: absolute;  
    top: 0;  
    left: 0;  
    display: block;  
    width: 100%;  
    height: 100%;  
    text-decoration: none;  
    z-index: 1;  
}
```

учитывайте, чтобы ссылка всегда растягивалась на ширину контента, нужно чтобы у `body, html` стояло `height: 100%.`

также желательно указать родителя в стилях для ссылки, где она вложена `position: relative;`

все это можно думаю зашить в ваш шаблон битрикса в header.php

Comment: Может Вы не правильно поняли?
Есть bakground (подложка/фон, в виде картинки, по краям сайта). Нужно, чтобы, когда на нее кликаешь, осуществлялся переход на заданную страничку (внутри самого сайта).

Стили прописать - это уже вторая часть. Картинка и с кодом, указанным выше, хорошо смотрится. Главное сделать эту картинку активной. 
Что значит внутри div c этим фоном? Этот фон пока только в css прописан. Следовательно ни в каком диве его нет. Нужно вписать в body, я так понимаю? Но разве не что-то вроде такого кода:
<a href="адрес страницы" ><img src="имя картинки"></a >
</div> 

Спасибо.

Comment: у вас получается картинка фоном у самого боди прописана ? 

если да, то тот код, который в верху тоже подойдет. и да можно вставить после body просто ссылку растянутую на всю область как выше опять же написано. правильно понимаю?

Comment: Хорошо, давайте отбросим, все что до этого было написано. Так как я ничего не понимаю.
Вопрос: что и где прописать, чтобы сделать подложку на сайт. Плюс, чтобы она еще и служила активной ссылкой.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8VvfT/ вот посмотрите пожалуйста это ли имелось в виду. по краям ссылки везде, в центре текущий контент сайта

Comment: да, все правильно!

Comment: хорошо ! =) это и описывалось в самом ответе в самом начале)

Comment: Хорошо, тогда попробую сделать, как Вы сказали)

Answer (score 0):

Тут не фоновое изображение становится ссылкой, а div блок.

Проще сделать так :

```css
.a1 {background-image: url(...);}
```

```html
<a href="http://gamingicons.ucoz.com/"><div class="а1"></div></a>
```

И получить тот же эффект.